# Rdd to Data Frame - i am getting output in the data frame table with " " like "2012-10-10" but my required output is without " " like 2012-10-10

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input file contains below input

```
"date","time","size","r_version","r_arch","r_os"  
"2012-10-01","00:30:13",35165,"2.15.1","i686","linux-gnu"  
"2012-10-01","00:30:15",212967,"2.15.1","i686","linux-gnu"  
"2012-10-01","02:30:16",167199,"2.15.1","x86_64","linux-gnu"
```

my present output is like

[present output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMfXP.png)

my required output is

[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVJpU.png)

I tried with below code

```
conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("logfile")
sc=SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("yuva").getOrCreate()
lines=sc.textFile("file:///SaprkCourse/filelog.txt")
lines=Seq("file:///SaprkCourse/filelog.txt").t
header = lines.first()
lines = lines.filter(lambda row : row != header)
values=lines.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
df=values.toDF(header.split(","))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check data type in data frame and cast it to String. Maybe, Data frame auto infer data type to date.
For Example, Pyspark will auto infer "2010-10-02" to date time.

Comment: In this case, maybe dateframe auto infer to string. You should check type of data

Comment: Hi 
not only for date but for every vale in the table " " should be removed for Example i took date and explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below option while creating the dataframe

```
option("quote", "\"")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: could you please check my code and let me know where i can insert that

Comment: @srikanth any particular reason you are not using dataframe API to read the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

hi I hope you are using pyspark2, if so you can simply write below command:

lines= spark.read.csv("file:///SaprkCourse/filelog.txt",header=True)

Else you can edit your code by adding a small function as shown below :

lines= sc.textFile("file:///SaprkCourse/filelog.txt")

header = lines.first()

lines = lines.filter(lambda row : row != header)

def text(x):

```
    k = x.replace('"','').strip().split(",")
    return k
```

values=lines.map(text)

df=values.toDF(header.replace('"','').split(","))

df.show()